# 2D Hermite interpolation on rirregular points

Tags: interpolation, hermite-polynomials

I am trying to generalize the principle of Hermite interpolation to 2D, over irregular data points.

In 1D, we have a sequence of points on which the value of a function and its first derivative is known. The Hermite interpolant is a piecewise cubic function such that on every interval a cubic polynomial is defined by the two values and two derivatives at the endpoints. This is enough to ensure $C_0$ and $C_1$ continuity.

Now in 2D, we can generalize by defining piecewise polynomial functions over a triangulation of the points, where every triangular patch is just defined by the function values and gradient values at the vertices. To ensure $C_0$ and $C_1$ continuity ("tangent plane continuity"), I want to enforce the following properties:

- The interpolant over a triangle is a bivariate polynomial defined by the values and gradient component values at the vertices ($9$ numbers);
- Furthermore, the values and gradient values *along the edges* are only depending on the (gradient) values at the *two vertices* they link.

I am looking for a simple way to establish suitable formulas, with a polynomial degree as low as possible. Notice that if we follow en edge, the gradient in the direction of the edge can be obtained as an ordinary $1D$ Hermite interpolation; but for the gradient in the transverse direction, I have no precise clue. I assume that the barycentric coordinates can be helpful here.

Is this kind of interpolant already known ? How can I address the problem ?

Note that I am not after a method to compute the gradients at vertices, just a way to enforce the continuity condition along edges.

Comment: "for the gradient in the transverse direction, I have no precise clue." I'm not familiar with the interpolation theory literature, but similar issues are encountered in finite element discretization of plate bending. There the simplest assumption used is that the slope in the transverse direction varies linearly along the edge, see e.g. [Batoz et al. 1980](https://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Publications_Prior_to_1998/A_Study_of_Three-Node_Triangular_Plate_Bending_Elements.pdf) eq. (22). This way the transverse slopes at adjacent elements always agree.

Comment: @Rahul: yep, I agree. Remains to convert this to the $(x,y)$ representation.

Comment: @Rahul: after deeper research, I found that Clough & Tocher initiated a classical method where every triangle is subdivided in three. Different variants have been designed since, and it turns out that the problem is not so simple.

Comment: Oh, interesting! Clough-Tocher interpolation is already implemented [in SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html), by the way.